# How to Object destructuring in child component in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the problem with Object destructuring in REACT here? Check the [CODEPEN HERE](https://codepen.io/drkfuture/pen/mdwbRBb) The same destructuring works outside React. How can I send object as an argument and have a parameterized destructure in the child component?

```
const MyComponent= ({name,age})=> { 
    return (
      <div>
        <h1> HI THERE I M {name}</h1>
      </div>
    );
}  


function App() {

  let person = { name: "ALEN", age : 40};
  return (
    <div>
      <MyComponent person={person} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `person` in props, not `name` and `age`, you can follow like this.

First destruct `person` from `props` then destruct `name` and `age` from `person`.

```
const MyComponent = ({ person }) => {
const { name, age } = person;
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> HI THERE I M {name}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: thnk u but the same works in plain javascript. I can pass an object as an argument of a function and destruct it right in the parameter of that same function. So I thought the same wud work here. E.g. foo(anObject) ,  ( {name, age} )=> {... }

Answer (score 5):

React will pass an object down to `MyComponent` that looks like this:

```js
{ person: { name: "ALEN", age: 40 } }
```

Because you specify the properties `name` and `age` in your object destructuring and not `person`, it will be undefined.

You can declare the function like this:

```js
const MyComponent = ({ person: { name,age } }) => { 
    return (
      <div>
        <h1> HI THERE I M {name}</h1>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: thnk u but the same works in plain javascript. I can pass an object as an argument of a function and destruct it right in the parameter of that same function. So I thought the same wud work here. E.g. foo(anObject) , ( {name, age} )=> {... } . We do use the object properties (if they have same name as variables) in object destructuring.